# How to place createMaterialTopTabNavigator inside ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Native (bare, not Expo). I am trying to place `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` inside a `ScrollView`. The reason why I want to do this is because on top of the tabs there will be a header containing an accordion, that on press can expand and display more content, so it has a dynamic height.

Here's a screenshot for more context:

[image: accordion above tabs]

Here is what I tried:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function MyNavigator() {
  const [isAccordionExpanded, setIsAccordionExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <CustomAccordion
        title={<Text>Accordion title</Text>}
        data={<Text>Accordion content when expanded</Text>}
        onToggleExpand={() => setIsAccordionExpanded(!isAccordionExpanded)}
        isExpanded={isWalletExpanded}
      />
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={Tab1} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={Tab2} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Tab3" component={Tab3} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

The problem is that the content in the tab screens disappears when I place the navigator in a `ScrollView` (like how it shows in the image I shared above). If I replace `ScrollView` with `View`, the content does appear, but there is a big empty space between the accordion component and the tabs, I'm assuming because the accordion height is dynamic so it adds extra space for it to expand.

[image: replacing scrollview with view]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can fix it by using contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}} then remove the style={{flex: 1}}. after that, the content will show up.